# What does "keep peace with" mean here?

Tags: meaning

What does "keep peace with" mean here? It is a little confusing to me.

> The poet Max Ehrmann says, “Whatever your labors and aspirations, in the noisy confusion of life, **keep peace with** your soul.” My peace is only possible because of the love and support of Bill, Chelsea, Marc, Charlotte, Aidan, and our entire family.
>
> Source: What Happened, by Hillary Rodham Clinton

I've looked for it on the internet and I could not find a satisfying answer. There was an answer which I thought it does not right for this sentence. The meaning was "Don't deviate from your principles" which did not seem right to me. Because this meaning does not fit the second sentence. Please help me to understand it.

Comment: Thank you for asking. The bad news is that a Stack Exchange question should be objective and specific enough that it has one clearly “right” answer. The meaning of a text or utterance is generally so subjective that we cannot give a “right” answer. This is why requests for literary criticism, discussion, analysis, and divining the author’s intent are generally off topic. This includes (but is not limited to) literature, lyrics, poetry, and legal documents. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”.

Comment: If you have an objective question, such as “What does (word) mean in this context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in this context?” then please [edit] to add the information our community needs in order to give a correct answer. Detail the effort you have already made to find an answer, solutions you have already rejected, and why. For example, what did you find in peer-reviewed sources, such as a dictionary, thesaurus, or grammar, or other questions on this site? See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.